# Unclaimed disk space but no actual physical disk present

Tags: linux, storage, hard-drive

I am working with Ubuntu server 12.04 and earlier this week we detected a bad disk in /dev/sdl. I was not able to query its mount point and it also had failed SMART tests.

Today I brought a brand new hard disk to replace the failed one (same brand and model)

However after installing the drive, I run:

```
  $ dmesg -t | tail
```

to see if the drive has been detected. Unfortunately I am not able to detect the drive.

Here is the output of `lshw | grep -A 5 disk`.

```
  disk:10 UNCLAIMED
  description: SCSI Disk
  physical id: 0.a.0
  bus info: scsi@6:0.10.0
```

How can this appear regardless of whether I have a disk in there or not?

My process for replacing failed disks is this:

- Physically locate bad disk
- Unmount and remove bad disk
- Insert new disk, run `dmesg | tail` to show disk is present
- Format disk
- Mount disk

For all the other disks, dmesg showed when they were inserted but not this time. Any thoughts?

Comment: There are a [large number of ways](http://serverfault.com/questions/190685/whats-the-best-way-to-get-info-about-currently-unmounted-drives/190700#190700) to get information about drives, scanning the output of dmesg is a relatively poor method.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the age of this question, it may be safe to assume the system's been rebooted.
However, there's another way to trigger a re-scan of the either the entire SCSI bus or just the device itself.

- Re-Scan the entire SCSI bus

  ```
  echo "- - -" > /sys/class/scsi_host/host0/scan
  ```
- Re-Scan just the device itself

  ```
  echo 1 > /sys/class/scsi_device/0:0:0:0/rescan
  ```

**Note:** You will have to confirm if `host0` or `0:0:0:0` are correct for that host/drive.