# What replaced vol_id in Debian 9.x "stretch"?

Tags: hard-drive, hardware, disk-volume, uuid

I was reading [this link](https://serverfault.com/questions/190685/whats-the-best-way-to-get-info-about-currently-unmounted-drives) and tried the [vol_id](https://linux.die.net/man/8/vol_id) command. From my research, it was part of the udev package, and I see it was [removed long ago](https://launchpad.net/debian/+source/cryptsetup/+changelog). What replaced vol_id in Debian 9.x "stretch"?  As a bonus for the future, I would like to find out how to determine where commands have been replaced, like is there a cross-reference online?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Dave S. commented the question you linked:

> 'vol_id' has since been renamed 'blkid', for anyone who happens to stumble upon this great answer. – Dave S. Feb 22 '13 at 14:29

For the "where commands have been replaced" question, if the command is a significant one, changes to it are likely to be mentioned in a distribution's release notes... which you should read before upgrading from one major release to another anyway. For something that is originally inteded to be used mainly by a particular subsystem or application only (like `vol_id` was for `udev`), you might have to check the package's changelogs.